# 'IServiceCollection' does not contains a definition for 'AddDbContext'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've installed EF 6.4.4 in my 'Service' project (class library).

In my 'WebApp' project (ASP.NET Core 6.0) I want to declare the DbContext in Program.cs. I've installed `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and added
`using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` on top of the file then

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Can't compile the project I have the following error :

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contains a definition for 'AdDbContext'

Comment: Did you forget to add the EF Core package? There's no EF Core 6.4.4. EF 6.4.4 is the old EF for .NET Framework package

Comment: `AdDbContext` is mispelled.  But in your code snippet its right.  Did you verify you dont have a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong package was added. [EntityFramework 6.4.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework) is the old EF library meant for .NET Framework applications, and knows nothing about the Dependency Injection middleware.

Use the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/7.0.0-preview.7.22376.2) package instead. The latest stable version is [6.0.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/6.0.8)